# Apache POI is causing stackoverflow

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, stack-overflow

I have written a code to read from and write into excels using apache poi.I have worked wit tens of excel and it was good. 
But while reading a cell in an excel I am getting hit by **stackoverflow** error.
The cell is a formulae cell and if this cell evaluates to something it's good but when it is empty- reading this cell gives StackOverflow.

```
XSSFCell cell = (XSSFCell) row_6.getCell(9);
String str = evaluator.evaluate(c).getStringValue(); // this  line causes stack overflow
return str;
```

I can't figure out what's wrong, in my all other excels same code is working fine. **If the cell is empty str is null or else it has some value**. But in this case, it's giving stack overflow when cell is empty.
One reason, I can think of is, if the cell is empty poi keeps on reading it again and again and causes stckoverflow. But this is not the expected behaviour. 
I am also not sure if anything is wrong with excel, I don't have expertise in that. Any suggestions are welcome. TIA.
I am attaching the full **stack trace**, if needed ave a look.

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeable(FormulaParser.java:461)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseRangeExpression(FormulaParser.java:311)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1509)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1467)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1454)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1827)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1955)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1939)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1896)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.intersectionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1869)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.unionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1849)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1495)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1467)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1454)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseUnary(FormulaParser.java:1521)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parseSimpleFactor(FormulaParser.java:1492)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.percentFactor(FormulaParser.java:1467)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.powerFactor(FormulaParser.java:1454)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.Term(FormulaParser.java:1827)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.additiveExpression(FormulaParser.java:1955)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.concatExpression(FormulaParser.java:1939)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.comparisonExpression(FormulaParser.java:1896)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.intersectionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1869)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.unionExpression(FormulaParser.java:1849)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:1997)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.FormulaParser.parse(FormulaParser.java:170)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.getFormulaTokens(XSSFEvaluationWorkbook.java:85)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:315)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.UnaryPlusEval.evaluate(UnaryPlusEval.java:38)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed1ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed1ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:158)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.UnaryPlusEval.evaluate(UnaryPlusEval.java:38)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed1ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed1ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:158)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.UnaryPlusEval.evaluate(UnaryPlusEval.java:38)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed1ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed1ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:158)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.AreaEvalBase.getAbsoluteValue(AreaEvalBase.java:100)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.singleOperandEvaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:29)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.TwoOperandNumericOperation.evaluate(TwoOperandNumericOperation.java:35)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.functions.Fixed2ArgFunction.evaluate(Fixed2ArgFunction.java:33)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluatorFactory.evaluate(OperationEvaluatorFactory.java:119)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:550)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:317)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateReference(WorkbookEvaluator.java:750)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRefEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRefEvaluator.java:48)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.SheetRangeEvaluator.getEvalForCell(SheetRangeEvaluator.java:74)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:51)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.LazyAreaEval.getRelativeValue(LazyAreaEval.java:45)
at org.apache.poi.sorg.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromAreaInternal(OperandResolver.java:163)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.chooseSingleElementFromArea(OperandResolver.java:120)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.eval.OperandResolver.getSingleValue(OperandResolver.java:64)
```

Comment: @Gagravarr http://stackoverflow.com/users/685641/gagravarr ,Please have a look.

Comment: Can you give the formulae of that cell ?

Comment: Is the cell you're trying to read, contains reference to another cell? Try temporarily changing the formula to a simple one (something like `=A1+B1` ). Does it still shows same error?

Comment: Are you sure it is an empty cell that shows this behaviour? I would suspect some circular reference in your excel-sheet - i.e. one cell referencing the contents of another cell and that one referencing back to the first one.

Comment: Yes, I guess there is something wrong with the excel. If I use a simple formula, the error is gone. @piet I guess there is some such dependency that is causing such behaviour. I am looking into if I can track it down.

Comment: @piet.t, Circular reference is taken care by excel itself, it would through circular reference error when you try to do that in excel.

Comment: @SrikanthA I just tried to insert a circular reference in an xlsx: it showed a wraning that it might produce incorrect results but when I clicked "OK" it accepted the circular reference without complaining any further.

Comment: @SrikanthA I have to look into formulae. Have no experience with excels. The formulae bar of cell shows `Error_Message` . Will let you know once i figure it out. Thnaks

Comment: The formulae in the cell refers to another cell of the different sheet, which has a formula as: `=IFERROR(OFFSET($C$51, Error_Number,0),0)`

Comment: Please open a bugzilla entry and attach your excel-sheet + code.